# Using an array to count coloured cells

Tags: vba, excel, multidimensional-array

Currently I have a worksheet which has different colored cells in it like the one below:

[currentsheet] http://imgur.com/na6nvNH

I am using an array to count the colored cells per column. Here is my a snippet of my code:

```
Dim difference(0 To 41) As Long
For Each mycell In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Differences").UsedRange
Dim col As Long
col = mycell.Column
 If ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Differences").Cells(mycell.Row,mycell.Column).Interior.Color = vbRed Then
difference(col) = difference(col) + 1
End If
Next mycell

Sheets("Summary").Cells(47, 3) = difference(0)
Sheets("Summary").Cells(48, 3) = difference(1)
Sheets("Summary").Cells(49, 3) = difference(2)
etc.
```

Which will list the amount of colored cells I have per column. I need help breaking this down so I can create a table which shows the number of colored cells per department. I have no idea on how to do this!

To make it easier to view I am looking to create this:

[FinalSheet] https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fh56.jpg

I should add: the amount of rows within the sheet can vary, they can also vary per department

Tried applying a column filter beginning with the first department and then counting the colored cells once the filter was applied, however since I am looking at every cell in the code above the result is still per column.

Comment: Is your  code running now and populating Differences correctly? Cause it seems it would break at Dim col As Long, I believe this should be at the top and not in the For loop. If it is not working please explain which part it fails at

Comment: @HolmesIV the code is running fine as long as I list all the columns in the array, i am trying to get to the final sheet as i have attached in the above. Currently i am just listing the amount of coloured cells per column

Answer (score 0):

It seems it would be a lot easier to use a multi dimensional array, so you would have Array(4,7) so some sudo code might look like. I could do real code, but you seem to know what your doing.

```
Select Case mycell.row
   Case 1 
      Array(1,Col) = Array(1,Col) + 1
   Case 2 
      Array(1,Col) = Array(1,Col) + 1
   Case 3
      Array(2,Col) = Array(2,Col) + 1
end select
```

The trick to a multi dimensional array is to think of it like a spread sheet, (2,2) = 3 rows, by 3 columns ... (3 because arrays start at 0)  The beauty of it is, if you do it this way when it comes to extract the data you simply put a double loop

```
For I =0 to Ubound(Array)
     For II = 0 to Ubound(Array,2)
          Cell(I,II).Value = Array(I,II)
     next
next
```

Comment: I am struggling with using multi dimensional arrays as I am only new to vb and simple arrays! If you could provide any more help it would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for an answer to this, a rather long method. However, I applied a filter and then set the range to only the visible cells instead of the used range in the whole worksheet